# Always redirect if user has specific role

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect

I have users with roles.  During the login of user, i want to check if the role is "gdmp_subscriber" and if it's true -> redirect to url specific url. If not just login. I've tried the following things, but withour success. Any ideas ?

Class:

```
<?php
define( 'GDMP_VERSION', '1.0' );
define( 'GDMP_PATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'GDMP_PATH_INCLUDES', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc' );
define( 'GDMP_FOLDER', basename( MP_PATH ) );
define( 'GDMP_URL', plugins_url() . '/' . MP_FOLDER );
define( 'GDMP_URL_INCLUDES', MP_URL . '/inc' );


class GD_Marketing_Portal {

    public function __construct() {
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'gdmp_on_activate_callback' );
        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'gdmp_on_deactivate_callback' );
        add_action('wp_login', array($this, 'redirect_to_mp'), 10, 2);
    }
    public function redirect_to_mp($user) {
        if (user_can($user, 'gdmp_subscriber')) {
            wp_redirect(home_url('marketing-portal'));
        }
    }
}
function gdmp_on_activate_callback() {
    $capabilities = array(
        'read' => true,
    );

    add_role( 'gdmp_subscriber', __( 'Marketing Portal Subscriber', 'gdmp' ), $capabilities );
}

function gdmp_on_deactivate_callback() {
    if( get_role( 'gdmp_subscriber' ) ) {
      remove_role( 'gdmp_subscriber' );
    }
}
$marketing_portal = new GD_Marketing_Portal();
```

And the page html :

```
get_header(); ?>
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
?>
<section class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        if ( ! post_password_required() ) {
        ?>
        <div class="column thumbnail-wrapper">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .column -->

        <div class="column title-wrapper">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1><!-- .heading-title -->
        </div><!-- .column -->

        <div class="column  subtitle-wrapper">
            <h4><?php echo $subtitle ?></h4><!-- .heading-title -->
        </div><!-- .column -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .row -->
    <?php
    if ( ! post_password_required() ) {
            ?>
            <?php if ( $form_1_shortcode || $form_2_shortcode ) : ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column" id="mp-form-tabs">
                        <ul>
                            <?php if ( $form_1_shortcode ) : ?>
                                <li><a href="#mp-form-1">Form 1</a></li>
                            <?php endif;
                            if ( $form_2_shortcode ) : ?>
                                <li><a href="#mp-form-2">Form 2</a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php if ( $form_1_shortcode ) : ?>
                            <div id="mp-form-1">
                                <p><?php echo do_shortcode( $form_1_shortcode ); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;
                        if ( $form_2_shortcode ) : ?>
                            <div id="mp-form-2">
                                <p><?php echo do_shortcode( $form_2_shortcode ); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </section>
    <?php
} else {
    auth_redirect();
}
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function redirect_users_by_role() {

    $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
    $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];

    if ( 'gdmp_subscriber' === $role_name ) {
        wp_redirect( get_home_url() . '/path' );
        exit;
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_users_by_role' );
```

Add the following to your functions.php.  It will redirect any users with the user role of 'gdmp subscriber' to your chosen url.